# Subcribe to LIsts Rather that Cards

Tags: trello

Is it possible to subscribe individuals to an entire list rather than only a card?  I want people to be able to get email updates on all changes to all cards in certain lists without having to drag their names to each individual card.  Is this possible?  They can view it all, but it is the email updates I am concerned about.

Comment: I'd also like to know that. I'll just let you know that you can subscribe to individual items by just hovering the mouse over them and pressing `s`.

Answer (score 2):

As I'm writing this, the feature you're asking for is marked "in development" on the official Trello dev board:

> https://trello.com/card/board-and-list-subscribe/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1260

I hope we're going to see it in a week or two.